# how to check what JavaScript functions have been called in firebug

Tags: javascript, function, firebug

I am editing a complex website.

Some jQuery functions are called in response to clicking on different elements (links, div, anchor, etc.).

How can I see what JavaScript function is called when I press on an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of the functions, add a `console.log(functionname)`. so whenever the function is called, you will see a line in console telling you the function's name.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can do this with the Profile button although I haven't used this myself yet.

Answer (score -1):

you can place a breakpoint on some  inside function and see if the program hits it (in firebug you can use script tab for placing breakpoint)

Answer (score -1):

In chrome/safari you can inspect the call stack on any breakpoint. I'm positive that firebug will let you do the same thing.

So set a breakpoint at the place where you wan to see what's calling it and then inspect the call stack to see what chain of calls led you to that point.

Warning: jQuery does a lot of anonymous functions so it can be a little tricky to trace back.

Comment: i am looking for the opposite....if i have 100 js functions i cannot use this method

Comment: @TrustWeb A stack trace/call stack is pretty much your only option.  Other than going to the code and following all the function calls.